# How to get XCode commandline tools for Leopard in 2014

Tags: xcode, leopard

It's been several years since Leopard, but today I found myself looking for the XCode commandline tools that would run on it. Specifically, version 3.1, as that is the last version that would run on Leopard.

However, the Apple developers download page does not provide any downloads for XCode tools for either Leopard or Snow Leopard.

Is anyone aware of any workign mirrors, or ways I could obtain the toolchain? I could of course compile the various included tools from source, but that would probably take much more time than I was planning to spend on this project.

<strike>On a related note; I feel Apple should just keep the old versions online at the download center. It's terrible practice to simply stop making older versions available for download.</strike>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never. mind. Of course one ends up solving something like this right after posting on StackExchange.

This is simply a naming thing. Apple started calling their development tools "command line tools" starting from 10.7, which is why I could not find the old dev tools when I searched for this. 'Xcode 3.1 Developer Tools' is the name of the download. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1596185/1711232) pointed me in the right direction.